# Compiling java source code to native exe

Tags: java, c++, object, native

Is it possible to compile java source code into native exe like C++?
Like C++ all headers files are included during compilation, all java library files that are required should be attached in that exe, and this exe should not be a bytecode but native exe instead and run without jvm.

So all I want to know is something like.. if I can replace all C++ syntax with Java syntax and compile to an exe file like one created by C++ compiler which run directly.

**Note: I am not talking about packers that wraps java classes in exe and ultimately requires jvm.**

Comment: And separately, make the first sentence actually your question, as that's what shows up on the front page.

Comment: No you can't that defeats the purpose of platform independence of Java. Why don't you use C++ instead?

Comment: *"...this exe should not be a bytecode but native exe instead and run without jvm..."* ***Why***? As opposed to the very good wrappers that make it *seem* that way to your users? (About which there are a couple of dozen questions and answers here on SO.) A difference that makes no difference *is* no difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only to-native-code Java compiler that I'm aware of is [The GNU Compiler for the Java<sup>tm</sup> Programming Language](https://gcc.gnu.org/java/).

But it's ***extremely unlikely*** you really need a to-native-code compiler. Packers like the ones you've dismissed can make your program *entirely self contained*, including installing a private JVM, seamlessly. I strongly recommend you [check out the options in this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file).

Comment: [see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147230/9878263) > "GCJ is dead. It was officially removed from the GCC project in 2016." See comments on @RichardCritten's answer (> [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcj)) (> [statement about deletion](https://tromey.com/blog/?p=911)).

Answer (score 7):

As of 2020-05 the current options include:

- javapackager (in openFX, add slimmed down JRE to executable)
- launch4J (35kb external dependency, option to check for and download or include JRE)
- GraalVM native image for real slim executables (but a bit more configuration for use of reflection)

Comment: javapackager was superseded by [`jpackage`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/392) in Java 16.

Comment: GraalVM native image still need the original jar file

Comment: @aldo: the native-image command generate executables directly from class- or jar-files. Afterwards the executable is independent of and can be distributed without the original class/jar-files.

Answer (score 4):

"GCJ is a portable, optimizing, ahead-of-time compiler for the Java Programming Language. It can compile Java source code to Java bytecode (class files) or **directly to native machine code**, and Java bytecode to native machine code."

see:
https://gcc.gnu.org/java/

Comment: Page no longer exists. It seems all references to GCJ have been wiped clean from gnu.org without mention.

Comment: This link still works https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcj/  There is currently no version 7 documentation I can see.

Answer (score 2):

I tried [`Excelsior JET`](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/evaluate) recently and it worked really well for compiling `JAR`s into native Windows binaries. The `JetpackII` utility allows you to deploy your application on a target machine without needing a Java installation. It may be a bit complicated to get used to but overall a brilliant choice.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a runnable jar from the source code.
2. To make an executable file, we will need a separate tool for it called Launch4j. The download link for this software is down below.

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

3. This tool adds a JRE(Minimum supported version) to the jar and creates an exe for windows machines.