# deploy java app as a windows service without installing third party software

Tags: java, windows-services

I need to install a java application onto another machine other than my own as a windows service. The issue is I cannot install any third party software on their machine. My restrictions are pretty the java i write and the software native to windows/microsoft.

I've read that I cannot convert a java application to a windows service without a third party, but could I use a third party to convert a java application to a .exe that can be used as a windows service and deploy it to another machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there really aren't options out there that get past the requirement for a JVM. See this similar question here: [Compiling java source code to native exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249838/compiling-java-source-code-to-native-exe)

And note that the GCJ mentioned in that post no longer exists nor supports any recent version of java as far as i know.

Then on that page there's a link to this question with a lot of options that DO involve packaging a JVM with your code: [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Comment: Is converting to a .exe enough to make it runnable as a service? I had read from https://dzone.com/articles/installing-a-java-application-as-a-windows-service  that just converting it to a .exe won't work because java uses a "scheduled executor".

Answer (score 1):

Do you consider java to be a third party service?
You need to include the JRE, if it's not installed on the machine.